# Question on Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many non-negative integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5= 20$ are there with $x_i\leq 8, i=1,2,3,4,5$
Is there any way to solve this question without considering multiple cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**:we basically seek the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the expansion $${(1+x+x^2..+x^8)}^5={(1-x^9)}^5{(1-x)}^{-5}=?$$

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Comment: @SKDash what do ypou want me to explain the final step? or how it is related to the coefficient?

Comment: how it is related to the coefficient

Comment: @SKDash think of $x^r$ as a value by multiplying with another $x^m$ we have $x^{r+m}$

Comment: how did $(1+x+x^2+…+x^8)^5$ become $ (1-x^9)^5(1-x)^5$?

Comment: @SKDash sum of gp..

Comment: okay makes sense

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @SKDash please show some attempts else  the question will be closed

Answer (score 0):

The number-theoretic partitions are well-studied.

A $k$-partition of $n$ is a word $x_1x_2 . . . x_k$ of length $k$ over the alphabet $\Bbb N$ where $x_1 + x_2 + . . . + x_k = n$.

Let $p(n,k)$ be the number of such words.

Then $p(n,1)=1$ (its the word $n$) and $p(n,n) = 1$ (its the word $11...1$).

Moreover, if $1<k<n$, then $p(n,k) = {n-1\choose k-1}$.

For instance, if $n=5$, then for $k=2$ we have the words $14,23,32,41$; for $k=3$, $113,131,311, 122, 212, 221$, and for $k=4$, $1112, 1121, 1211, 2111$.

Now consider correspondingly words over $\Bbb N_0$ by including $0$'s.